# Grouping a checkbox with a corresponding input field

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, laravel

I am trying to find a way to group a checkbox and input field so a user can only input data into the field if the checkbox has been selected. I currently have a generated checkbox field (values from table) with a corresponding input field.

My current solution is:

```
    @foreach($labourTypes as $id => $name)
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                      {!! Form::checkbox("labour_types[]", $id) !!} {{$name}}
                </label>
                {!! Form::input('number', 'required_labour_type_hours[]', '') !!}
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

And for inputting into the database:

```
    $required_labour_hours = array_filter($required_labour_hours);
    $required_labour_hours = array_values($required_labour_hours);
    foreach(array_combine($labour_types, $required_labour_hours) as $labour_type => $hours) {
        DB::table('required_labour_type')->insert([
            'id' => null,
            'labour_type_id' => $labour_type,
            'required_labour_type_hours' => $hours
        ]);
    }
```

This is my current workaround, but it does not prevent (and messes up inserting) if the user were to fill out an input field that does not have the corresponding checkbox ticked.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHYR3.png

I am trying to find a way to make it so input is only allowed if the corresponding checkbox is selected, or to group them into an array prior inserting, and drop the ones that have no checkbox selected before inputting? I am new to laravel and php in general, so I am having a hard time coming up with a fool-proof workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery on the front end to control the input from the user. I would also validate the data on the server side just be to safe. Using jQuery, you could easily make the input fields readonly if the checkbox was not checked, and update as needed. This code assumes that the input field is one of `type="text"`. You could easily update to support multiple input types.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.checkbox').each(function() {

        var cbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]'),
            inp = $(this).find('input[type=text]');

        cbox.on('change', function(evt) {

            if( $(this).is(':checked') )
                inp.removeAttr('readonly');
            else
                inp.attr('readonly', true);

        });

        //init
        if( ! cbox.is(':checked') )
            inp.attr('readonly', true);

    });

});
```

On the server side, this would be as simple as checking for the existence of the checkbox. If a checkbox is not checked, it is not sent to the server during the form submission. So using something like:

```
if( isset($_POST['some_checkbox']) ) {
    //sanitize, validate, and save the value of the corresponding text field
} // else do nothing with this text field
```

Comment: I am currently working on another part of my application, so I haven't gotten around to validating the data server side yet, but the jQuery read only did exactly what I needed. Thanks.